# Adding select boxes dynamically with Jquery

Tags: jquery

Here is my Senario, I want to add selectboxes daynamically by clicking add more buton but i also want the value exclude from generated select box which is selected previously. i want this with jquery, thanks in advance, kindly guide in detail.

here is my code

```
div id="testingDiv1" class="clonedInput" align="center">
<select name="somename" class="form-control" id="select">
<option value="PleaseSelectOne">Please Select One</option>
<option value="somevalue">somevalue</option>
<option value="somevalue">somevalue</option>
<option value="somevalue">somevalue</option>
<option value="somevalue">somevalue</option>
</select>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
      $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length, 
            newNum = new Number(num + 1), /
            newElem = $('#testingDiv' + num).clone().attr('id', 'testingDiv' + newNum).fadeIn('normal'); 


            newElem.find('.test-select').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_select').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_select').val('');
         $('#testingDiv' + num).after(newElem);
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);
        if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
      });
      $('#btnDel').click(function () {


          var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

            $('#testingDiv' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {
              $(this).remove();

                if (num - 1 === 1) $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);

                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "ADD MORE");
              });

          return false;

        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
      });
      $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Please add some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amir I have updated the jQuery to suit your requirement kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/q1ehqv5d/1/

**Updated jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('.clonedInput').length, 
            newNum = new Number(num + 1), 
            newElem = $('#testingDiv' + num).clone().attr('id', 'testingDiv' + newNum).fadeIn('normal'); 
// Store the block in a variable
    var $block = $('.clonedInput:last');

        // Grab the selected value
    var theValue = $block.find(':selected').val();

        // Clone the block 
    var clone = $block.clone();

        // Find the selected value in the clone, and remove
    if(theValue !="PleaseSelectOne")
    clone.find('option[value=' + theValue + ']').remove();
// Grab the select in the clone
var $select = clone.find('select');
var newId="testingDiv"+newNum;
console.log(newId);
    // Update its ID by concatenating theValue to the current ID
$select.parent().attr('id', newId);

         $('#testingDiv' + num).after(clone);
        $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);
        if (newNum == 5) $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', true).prop('value', "You've reached the limit");
      });
      $('#btnDel').click(function () {


          var num = $('.clonedInput').length;

            $('#testingDiv' + num).slideUp('slow', function () {
              $(this).remove();

                if (num - 1 === 1) $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);

                $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false).prop('value', "ADD MORE");
              });

          return false;

        $('#btnAdd').attr('disabled', false);
      });
      $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent provided any code i tried to recreate the scenario kindly check 
https://jsfiddle.net/q1ehqv5d/

**HTML**

```
<button class="addMore">
Add More
</button>
<div class="main">
<input type="checkbox">One<br>
<input type="checkbox">Two<br>
<input type="checkbox">Three<br>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.addMore').on('click', function(){

        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');

    $('.main').append('<input type=\"checkbox\">Some Text<br>');
  });
});
```

Comment: i reformated the code previously i was paste the wrong code here

Comment: what do you mean by "value exclude from generated select box which is selected previously" do you mean you want to reset the first select box or create a new selectbox without the value selected in 1st selectbox?

Comment: yes exactly. i want to create new dropdown without the value which is already selected in previous dropdown. i don't want to reset the value of previously seleted dropdown

Comment: Why no one giving me an answer